# Cant log in to app after deployed on Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have deployed my doccano app on Cloud Run but cant cant log in. It keeps complaining about the "Incorrect username or password"

[image]

I think this is because I havent given the auth argument, on my local I usually need use to start the container with this kind of cmd:

```
docker container create --name doccano \
  -e "ADMIN_USERNAME=admin" \
  -e "ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@example.com" \
  -e "ADMIN_PASSWORD=password" \
  -p 8000:8000 chakkiworks/doccano
```

But I dont know where on GCP Cloud Run where can I add such information [image]

can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add your environment variables just next to the CONTAINER section which is **VARIABLES** on the Advanced settings, you set them as Name/Value pair.

Or update your service via command line:

```
gcloud run services update SERVICE --update-env-vars KEY1=VALUE1,KEY2=VALUE2
```

> If you have multiple env variables, separate them with a comma ','.

However in production, please [**avoid storing your sensitive info**](https://diogomonica.com/2017/03/27/why-you-shouldnt-use-env-variables-for-secret-data/) as environment variables because they can be easily acccessed in plaintext. I recommend that you take your time and learn how to use [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets).